# Is it possible to Consumes Sharepoint Webservices(SOAP-based) into ORACLE DB using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, web-services, sharepoint, list, plsql

We have a requirement to store Sharepoint List Data into Oracle.

Is it possible to Consumes Sharepoint Webservices(SOAP-based) into ORACLE DB using PL/SQL, like to access _vti_bin/lists.asmx?op=GetList and parse the list data and store in the DB.

Has anybody tried this ??? Are there any things (Security, environment) things to consider before diggin into this route??

I think PL/SQL has the support to call Web services and parse the XML to store in the DB.

Help is appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible (not sure if any of the Sharepoint Webservices are non-standard).  Depending on your database version here are 2 articles that show how to call a SOAP webservice via PLSQL:

Oracle 9i and higher:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ConsumingWebServices9i.php

Oracle 10g and up:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/utl_dbws10g.php

Comment: Thx for the links, looks like it's possible; Sharepoint follows standard SOAP, looking for the responses who has already tried this

Comment: Looks like there is problem regardging security ( NTLM / Kerboros Authentication) How to use sys.utl_http or sys.utl_dbws to call a .Net webservice with Kerberos- or NTLM authentication (we're currently struggling with this).

Comment: What is the setup of your infrastructure?  You could add more information to your question detailing what your stack looks like and exactly what you are trying to do.  It is possible with more information that other solutions may be suggested.

Comment: We have Sharepoint Site using NTLM/Kerboros Authentication over SSL. When I try to access the webservice with anonymous access it works, but either with NTLM/Kerboros or SSL it fails

I have used sys.utl_http.set_authentication(http_req,<<username>>,<<password>>,'Basic',false); , but still no use.

Is there any schemes other than 'Basic' , which we can use here

Help Appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

Since the standard Sharepoint web services can be a pain to work with (raw CAML is pretty evil...), and you may have security/authorization issues, may I suggest the following:

- Create your own .NET webservice in C# as a wrapper to the standard Sharepoint services. Create a clean interface with the parameters and return values that you need, and handle any security issues in .NET code.
- If appropriate, put some kind of security on top of your web service (password as parameter to service, Basic Authentication, etc.) and perhaps deploy it using HTTPS.
- Have your PL/SQL code call the new web service using UTL_HTTP (or better yet, use one of the many wrapper packages that exist, see http://ora-00001.blogspot.com/2009/07/calling-soap-web-service-from-plsql-by.html for an example).

In short, use Microsoft tools & technologies to create your own, simplified service, and then use PL/SQL to talk with that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Oracle documentation on UTL_HTTP, the set authentication only supports BASIC HTTP and Amazon S3 types, so NTLM is out of the question.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_http.htm#sthref16700

It seems to me that the "best" approach is to create another web service that acts a wrapper and allows for either basic or anonymous access.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of NTLM for PL/SQL here, which (in combination with UTL_HTTP) will allow you to call Sharepoint Web Services directly from PL/SQL:

http://ora-00001.blogspot.com/2011/08/ntlm-for-plsql.html

Note that if your site uses HTTPS, you need to set up an Oracle Wallet, too, and use that in your HTTP calls.